# MongoDB Show Current User

Tags: mongodb

How do I show the current user that I'm logged into the mongo shell as? This is useful to know because it is possible to change the user that you are logged in as—e.g. `db.auth("newuser", "password")`—while in the interactive shell. One can easily lose track.

#### Update

Using the accepted answer as a base, I changed the prompt to include user, connection, and db:

Edit `.mongorc.js` in your home directory.

```
function prompt() {
    var username = "anon";
    var user = db.runCommand({connectionStatus : 1}).authInfo.authenticatedUsers[0];
    var host = db.getMongo().toString().split(" ")[2];
    var current_db = db.getName();

    if (!!user) {
        username = user.user;
    }

    return username + "@" + host + ":" + current_db + "> ";
}
```

**Result:**

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
connecting to: test

anon@127.0.0.1:test> use admin
switched to db admin

anon@127.0.0.1:admin> db.auth("a_user", "a_password")
1

a_user@127.0.0.1:admin>
```

Comment: Your code may show a wrong user, e.g.: after having authenticated, change the db and authenticate as another user. In this case, the `connectionStatus.authInfo.authenticatedUsers` array will contain both users. Since your code reads always the 1st array element, you may end up showing the wrong user. 
Btw. using the **last** array entry wouldn't be perfect because when you change back to a db for which you had already authenticated and re-authenticate, the corresponding array element will be **replaced**, so it keeps it former array position, so the last array element might be incorrect too.

Comment: Very useful even given the comment above (user may be wrong). Ive added the line  if(host === undefined) host = 'localhost'

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The `connectionStatus` command shows authenticated users (if any, among some other data):

```
db.runCommand({connectionStatus : 1})
```

Which results in something like bellow:

```
{
    "authInfo" : {
            "authenticatedUsers" : [
                    {
                            "user" : "aa",
                            "userSource" : "test"
                    }
            ]
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

So if you are connecting from the shell, this is basically the current user

You can also add the user name to prompt by overriding the `prompt` function in `.mongorc.js` file, under OS user home directory. Roughly:

```
prompt = function() {
    user = db.runCommand({connectionStatus : 1}).authInfo.authenticatedUsers[0]
    if (user) {
        return "user: " + user.user + ">"
    }
    return ">"
}
```

An example:

```
$ mongo -u "cc" -p "dd"
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
connecting to: test
user: cc>db.auth("aa", "bb")
1
user: aa>
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thorough and very helpful. The additional prompt information is great advice. Much appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Your code may show a wrong user, e.g.: after having authenticated, change the db and authenticate as another user. In this case, the `connectionStatus.authInfo.authenticatedUsers` array will contain both users. Since your code reads always the 1st array element, you may end up showing the wrong user. 
Btw. using the **last** array entry wouldn't be perfect because when you change back to a db for which you had already authenticated and re-authenticate, the corresponding array element will be **replaced**, so it keeps it former array position, so the last array element might be incorrect too.

Comment: @Kay, looks like this is not valid (anymore). When I try this scenario then I get an error `too many users are authenticated` for every command. See [Authentication Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication/#authentication-methods)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit you're right, this has changed - mongodb keeps evolving for sure.

Comment: If one like to reuse the default prompt you can use function `defaultPrompt()`, e.g. `return "user: " + user.user + " " + defaultPrompt()` prompts current user and ReplicaSet name + status.

Comment: this saved my ass, I was logging into a bitnami mongo cluster for the first time that was built using a helm chart and I couldn't run commands because I wasn't "authenticated". Since the helm charts were building things it was hard to tell if there was a user or not. After switching to the admin db with `use admin` I ran this command and was able to see that there are no users which was my problem. Thanks!