# MongoDB why db.auth does not switch user?

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I have an admin user in the DB myNewDB

```
[admin] user: root>use myNewDB
switched to db myNewDB
[myNewDB] user: root>show users
{
"_id" : "myNewDB.superAdmin",
"user" : "superAdmin",
"db" : "myNewDB",
"roles" : [
    {
        "role" : "userAdmin",
        "db" : "myNewDB"
    },
    {
        "role" : "readWrite",
        "db" : "myNewDB"
    },
    {
        "role" : "dbAdmin",
        "db" : "myNewDB"
    }
    ]
}
```

when I try to authenticate as superAdmin: it seems to work

```
[myNewDB] user: root>db.auth("superAdmin","superAdmin123")
1
[myNewDB] user: root>
```

but I'm still connected as user 'root', should I not be authenticated as :

```
[myNewDB] user: superAdmin>
```

UPDATE

here is my monger.js

```
 prompt = function() {
     database = db.getName()
    user = db.runCommand({connectionStatus :   
     1}).authInfo.authenticatedUsers[0]
    if (user) {
        return "["+ database +"] " + "user: " + user.user + ">"
     }
     return "["+ database +"] " + ">"
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using the mongo shell, and you are presumably using a [.mongorc.js](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#mongorc-js-file) file which is how you're getting the customized prompt with a display of the current user and database.

I would suggest that you look at your `.mongorc.js` file and/or share it here. The prompt should change when you authenticate. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414608/mongodb-show-current-user) for an example `.mongorc.js` file.

**EDIT**:
Looking further, I suspect that you're running into the case where you can be authenticated against multiple databases. And your `.mongorc.js` is probably naively just grabbing the first user. Try running your example again and run `db.runCommand({connectionStatus : 1})` which would show multiple users.

Comment: Thanks a lot helm...  MongoDB doc is not so easy to understand for people discovering it...  db.runCommand({connectionStatus : 1}). effectively shows the 2 authenticated users against 2 databases... thanks for the tips and links...