# MongoDB - Who is the user behind connection?

Tags: mongodb, security, pymongo

In mongodb, I can run db.currentOp(), for example to see current running operations:

```
...
  "inprog": [
    {
      "host": "localhost:27088",
      "desc": "conn38932837",
      "connectionId": 38932837,
      "client": "localhost:55676",
      "clientMetadata": {
        "driver": {
          "name": "PyMongo",
          "version": "3.6.1"
        },
```

When conn38932837 has original connected, I can see in the log:

```
2015-07-28T06:41:54.832+0000 I ACCESS   [conn38932837] Successfully authenticated as principal mark on database
```

So I can see **mark** is the user.

Is there a way to get this data online without the logs ?

Comment: See this answer which demonstrates it on pure MongoDB level: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21417240/150978

Comment: Thanks. But this is not what I am after. This will show the user of the current session. As an admin, I want to see other connections running queries (I see this via db.currentOp()) and than who is the authenticated user for each of these connections.